# Smart object not directly editable in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: Error When Deleting A selection]

> Adobe Photoshop CC 2017
>
> Could not complete your request because the smart object is not directly editable

Any way to fix this?

I tried cutting the image parts; it didn’t work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

1. Open the image you want to edit.
2. Go to the *Layer* tab.
3. Click on the *Lock* icon to unlock the image layer:

   [image: Click ON Lock]
4. Select the area and press delete. It will work.
5. Save the file and import to to any other image if you want.